# pygame throwing: cam.start() OSError: ioctl(VIDIOC_STREAMON) failure : 22, Invalid

Tags: pi-4, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, pygame

I am trying to work with raspberry pi 4 and OV9281-110 camera ( https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/OV9281-110_Camera)

When I try to run pygame to read camera input I get the following error:

```
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.9.2)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "folderPath/test2pygame.py", line 10, in <module>
    cam.start()
OSError: ioctl(VIDIOC_STREAMON) failure : 22, Invalid argument
```

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
import pygame
import pygame.camera
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()
camlist = pygame.camera.list_cameras()
if camlist:
    cam = pygame.camera.Camera(camlist[0])
    cam.start()
    image = cam.get_image()
    print(image)
```

Could someone help me figure out what is wrong or how to fix it?

Comment: Check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74066991/pygame-throwing-cam-start-oserror-ioctlvidioc-streamon-failure-22-inval/) please. Its not solution to original question but a different solution to help read camera data.